Matrix Rain; Except Random Numbers Turn Yellow
I just started learning Batch by myself and I was trying to make a matrix thing for fun. What I am trying to make is a Batch program that displays a "Matrix Digital Rain." Except, whenever a %random:~-1% number is EQU to another %random:~-1% (Destined Digit), it is supposed to display that destined digit in a different color. Visual Idea
It was fairly easy to do the matrix part; However, making one digit appear in a different color is a different dimension for a noob. So far I have succeeded in: making the matrix rain, making texts appear in different colors, and making a condition for a destined digit. Is this even possible?
**Problems are: **
A. How do I detect destined numbers from the matrix rain and make them appear as yellow (SEPARATELY) without visibly disrupting the matrix rain?
B. How do I create more vertical lines of this?
I've attached links, from where I got answers from, below; Along with my current batch script.
Custom # of %random% Digits: How to generate 4 digit random numbers in a batch file?
Different Text Colors: How do I make one particular line of a batch file a different color then the others?
@echo off
color 02
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)

cls

:start
Ping -l 1 -n 1 -w 1000 1.1.1.1 -4 1>nul 2>&1 REM"delay cause too fast"
set num1=%random:~-2%
set num2=%random:~-2%
set dn=%random:~-2%
if %num1% EQU %num2% (call :color 06 "%random:~-2% %dn% %random:~-2%" & goto start) else (echo %random:~-2% %dn% %random:~-2% & goto start)

:color
echo off
echo %DEL% > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1

I've tried echo %random:~-1% . . . %dn% %random:~-1% but all it does is have one line of random numbers that occasionally turn yellow. It would be perfect if it could appear across different vertical lines randomly.
I'll be looking into arrays for now but I don't think I'll be getting it soon. Thank you in advance for answering!!! :D

I am building the color technique 2011 to work on Windows XP. These days you should just use ANSI escape sequences.

Yoooooo. I can't believe I'll be basing my answer twice from the same person! I have never heard of ANSI esc seqs before so your answer looked scary to a newbie. Now that I've heard of ANSI, I'll be using it a lot! Thank you so much for improving CMD!

This DosTips topic from Jun, 2012 may be of interest.

Your code with ansi escape sequences and some more columns.
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set numCols=8

for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "ESC=%%a"

cls
set "off=%ESC%[m"
set "red=%ESC%[0;31m"
set "red_light=%ESC%[1;31m"
set "green=%ESC%[32m"
set "yellow=%ESC%[33m"

REM for /L %%i in (30 1 39) do (
REM     echo %%i: %ESC%[0;%%im TEXT %OFF%
REM     echo %%i: %ESC%[1;%%im TEXT %OFF%
REM )

:start
Ping -l 1 -n 1 -w 1000 1.1.1.1 -4 1>nul 2>&1 REM"delay cause too fast"
for /L %%n in (1 1 %numCols%) do (
    set "col[%%n]=!random:~-2!"
)

if !col[1]! GTR !col[3]! (
    set "col[1]=%yellow%!col[1]!%OFF%"
)
if !col[2]! GTR !col[3]! (
    set "col[5]=%red%!col[5]!%OFF%"
)
set "line="
for /L %%n in (1 1 %numCols%) do (
    set "line=!line!!col[%%n]! "
)
echo !line!
goto :start


Update: I finally got what I wanted the way I wanted it. Thanks to the previous and the only answer and some enlightenment, I was able to improve upon the earlier code (shown on the question.) Anyways here's how I did it, hopefully this helps someone else in the future :D
@echo off
color 02
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "ESC=%%a"
set "yellow=%ESC%[33m"
set "green=%ESC%[32m"
cls

:start
set "det1=%random:~-1%" REM change these two to control chance of 
set "det2=%random:~-1%" REM yellow characters
set randdet=0
if %det1% EQU %det2% SET /A randdet=%RANDOM% * (16 - 1 + 1) / 32768 + 1
set "cdn=%yellow%!random:~-1!%green%"

set rand11=%random:~-1%
set rand12=%random:~-1%
set rand13=%random:~-1%
set rand14=%random:~-1%
set rand21=%random:~-1%
set rand22=%random:~-1%
set rand23=%random:~-1%
set rand24=%random:~-1%
set rand31=%random:~-1%
set rand32=%random:~-1%
set rand33=%random:~-1%
set rand34=%random:~-1%
set rand41=%random:~-1%
set rand42=%random:~-1%
set rand43=%random:~-1%
set rand44=%random:~-1%

if %randdet% EQU 1 set rand11=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 2 set rand12=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 3 set rand13=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 4 set rand14=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 5 set rand21=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 6 set rand22=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 7 set rand23=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 8 set rand24=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 9 set rand31=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 10 set rand32=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 11 set rand33=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 12 set rand34=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 13 set rand41=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 14 set rand42=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 15 set rand43=%cdn%
if %randdet% EQU 16 set rand44=%cdn%

set set1=%rand11% %rand12% %rand13% %rand14%
set set2=%rand21% %rand22% %rand23% %rand24%
set set3=%rand31% %rand32% %rand33% %rand34%
set set4=%rand41% %rand42% %rand43% %rand44%

set randline=%set1%  %set2%  %set3%  %set4%
echo %randline%

goto start

